# Can a smart contract be set up so that a function to forward funds sends a set percentage of the Ether received to 2 or more contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, openzeppelin, fallback-function, payable

For example the the openzeppelin crowdsale contract has a function that sends ether to a wallet address. Could this method include logic to send 60% of the funds received to Alice's wallet and 40% to Bob's wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called payment splitting.

It does not need to be built in to the crowdsale smart contract. You can simply create another smart contract that is a payment splitter. This splitter contract will split incoming payments in any programmable way.

For the crowdsale contract then just set the splitter smart contract address as the benefactor wallet.

Comment: Thank you Mikko. Do you know where I can find an example of a contract that has a programmable implementation of the payment splitting in it, for reference?